# Wordpress paramlinks change from plain to post name resulting in 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Hello I have a WordPress site and I changed the paramlinks from plain to post name. All my posts are showing 404 not found. I tried to check all possible causes but I could not find why it is not working.

My .htaccess is as below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Apache mode rewrite is enabled, the command `a2enmod rewrite` gives:

```
Module rewrite already enabled
```

PHP info shows `mod_rewrite` in Loaded Modules.

My vhost is as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public_html
        ErrorLog /var/www/mysite/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/mysite/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory "/var/www/mysite/public_html">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help on this please? Thanks.

Comment: please save again parmalinks from wp-admin and check might it works.

Comment: I did but I still get Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. This is very wired I don't see anything wrong with my settings.

Comment: I noticed that I'm running https self signed SSL and the paramslink work only with http and not https, I tried to add <Directory... to the apache default-ssl.conf file vhost too but it seems not working yet.

Comment: I got it to work, I had a wrong path to public_html folder in <Directory ... in the default-ssl.conf file.